# Debezium Postgres Kafka Connector heartbeat is not committing LSN

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a Postgres Db on AWS RDS and a kafka connect connector (Debezium Postgres) listening on a table. The configuration of the connector:

```
{
  "name": "my-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "database.dbname": "my_db",
    "database.user": "my_user",
    "max.queue.size": "32000",
    "slot.name": "my_slot",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "publication.name": "my_publication",
    "database.server.name": "postgres",
    "heartbeat.interval.ms": "1000",
    "database.port": "my_port",
    "include.schema.changes": "false",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "table.whitelist": "public.my_table",
    "tombstones.on.delete": "false",
    "database.hostname": "my_host",
    "database.password": "my_password",
    "name": "my-connector",
    "max.batch.size": "10000",
    "database.whitelist": "my_db",
    "snapshot.mode": "never"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "connector": "my-connector",
      "task": 0
    }
  ],
  "type": "source"
}
```

The table is not updated as frequently as other tables, which initially led to replication lag like this:

```
SELECT slot_name,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), restart_lsn)) as replicationSlotLag,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), confirmed_flush_lsn)) as confirmedLag,
  active
FROM pg_replication_slots;
           slot_name           | replicationslotlag | confirmedlag | active
-------------------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------
 my_slot                       | 1664 MB            | 1664 MB      | t
```

It would get so large that it would threaten using up all disk space.

I added a heartbeat, and if I log onto a kafka broker and set up a console consumer like this: `./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server my.broker.address:9092 --topic __debezium-heartbeat.postgres --from-beginning --consumer.config=/etc/kafka/consumer.properties`
 It would dump out all the heartbeat messages, and then show a new one every 1000ms.

However, the size of the slots still grows and grows. If I do something like insert a dummy record into the table, it sets the slot back to a small lag, so that works.

I would like to do this with a heartbeat though. I do not want to insert periodic messages since it sounds like it would add complexity. Why is the heartbeat not reducing the slot size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please take a look at https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/postgresql.html#wal-disk-space

You really need to emit the periodic messages but there is a help for it now - https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-1815

Comment: Thank you for the link to the Issue. I'm glad to know it's on the team's radar. I will go with the periodic messages solution, then.

Comment: so, we don't have to do periodic messages anymore? I see Jiri's comment in the issue that the feature is released..