# Debezium Heartbeat Action not firing

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

When working with Debezium and Postgres, we're seeing an issue where the heartbeat doesn't seem to be working. We have created a dummy table in the target database for performing the heartbeat actions on, but we don't ever see any change to the data in that table.

We've enabled the heartbeat, as we're seeing the same behavior that it was designed to address, namely https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-1815.

We're using Postgres 12, and Debezium 1.3 (or 1.5, have experimented with both)

The configuration is

```
{
  "name": "my-service-outbox",  
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector", 
    "plugin.name":"pgoutput",
    
    "database.hostname": "dbhostname", 
    "database.port": "5432", 
    "database.user": "user", 
    "database.password": "password", 
    "database.dbname" : "dbname", 
    "database.server.name": "dbservername", 
    
    "table.include.list": "public.outbox",
    "publication.autocreate.mode" : "filtered",
    "snapshot.mode":"exported",

    "heartbeat.interval.ms": 1000,
    "heartbeat.action​.query" :"INSERT INTO public.heartbeat (id, ts) VALUES (1, NOW()) ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET ts=EXCLUDED.ts;"
  }
}
```

Related, but no solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60808620/97879

It feels like we've missed something to *enable* the heartbeat, but not seeing anything besides ensuring the interval is set.

EDIT: The heartbeat is working, as we can see messages in the heartbeat topic. But the database action is not being performed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a zero-width space in the documentation so if you copied it the string contains it and it means it is not the option name expected by Debezium.

Comment: To clarify, the zero-width whitespace is after "heartbeat.action" (you'll notice it when stepping through the property name with the cursor in your editor/IDE, there's one extra step, seemingly without progress). We had added them in the docs for wrapping long option names on small screens, assuming they'd not be copy/paste-able. Seems we were wrong. We'll fix that, I've logged [DBZ-3087](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-3087) for it.

Comment: Ok, initially it didn't seem like that changed anything. Once I had manually retyped it, and posted the config again, nothing seemed to have changed.  Selecting from the heartbeat table returned the same static time.  BUT--after some data was added to the table in my "table.include.list", the heartbeat began working.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

My heartbeat action is not working either, unless there are action in the DB, if there are nothing happen in the DB, the heartbeat action just not triggering unless I manually insert something. Which is causing trouble, because for any empty/new DB, the heartbeat action just won't trigger

Answer (score 1):

Found this google group discussion( https://groups.google.com/g/debezium/c/39mmGEHii_8 ) where Gunnar mentions this -

*The core heartbeat feature [1] regularly emits messages to the heartbeat topic, allowing to acknowledge processed WAL offsets also in case only events in filtered tables occur (this is what you observe). Heartbeat action queries [2] (which require the table and inclusion in publication) are useful to address situations with multiple databases, where the connector is receiving changes from one database with otherwise no/low traffic, again allowing to acknowledge offsets in this case.
--Gunnar
[1] https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-property-heartbeat-interval-ms
[2] https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-property-heartbeat-action-query*

In the group discussion he mentions that we have to add this heartbeat table to the publication for this feature to work. This should help.

I will try it and keep you updated.

Edit: Update:

Added the heartbeat table to publication. Didn't make any difference. This issue is still open.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue and I did following to make it work

- create a heartbeat table in the same Schema which is used for debezium CDC
- include the heartbeat table in your publication
- include following configurations in the connector

  "heartbeat.interval.ms": "5000",

  "heartbeat.action.query" :"INSERT INTO respawned.pg_heartbeat (id, heartbeat_ts) VALUES (1, NOW()) ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET heartbeat_ts=EXCLUDED.heartbeat_ts;",
- deploy the connector
- add few insert statements into any of the tables that you have created kafka topics for change data capture
- run the insert query into heartbeat table through query editor manually or so.

  INSERT INTO respawned.pg_heartbeat (id, heartbeat_ts) VALUES (1, NOW()) ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET heartbeat_ts=EXCLUDED.heartbeat_ts;

Answer (score 0):

heartbeat.action.query doesn't seem to be working for me as well.
If there is no data flowing in the tables, the wal keeps growing due to activity in other databases. heartbeat.action.query should resolve this issue and I should not wait for another entry into the table I am streaming, to reduce the Wal size but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29932881)

Comment: I wanted to add a comment but SO didn't allow me to because of low reputation

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I have just experienced a similar issue, albeit I think it's not exactly the same as your issue but I'm posting here in case it's of use to anyone.  In a nutshell, the connector status was RUNNING, there were no errors in the connect log (nor in postgres's log), but the heartbeat table was empty - suggesting the action was not firing.

The database schema in my case appeared also to be empty (it's a new prod db), but I was expecting the heartbeat action to fire nonetheless.  A similar setup on different schemas in the same database was working - there were beats in the table, despite there being nothing as far as I could tell in the schema tables.

I found there were no heartbeat topics (either with or without the debezium prefix) for the schema for which there were no rows in the heartbeat table; everything looked good.  So I just tried a manual insert into the heartbeat table, and that was sufficient to kick off the heartbeats, and of course the heartbeat topics got created.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue (`using debezium v1.9,  PostgreSQL 10.20`), Heart beat configuration like below

```
heartbeat.interval.ms: 3000
heartbeat.action.query: "INSERT INTO public.debezium_heartbeat (last_heartbeat_ts,connector) VALUES (NOW(),'source-postgres-studio-1');"
```

We have started with default mode (`snapshot.mode = initial`) snapshot almost took 6 hours. during this 6 hours no heart beat query triggered. after snapshot completed (become CDC), debezium connector started triggering `heartbeat.action.query`