# Debezium heartbeat table not updating

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc, heartbeat

There is already a question [Debezium Heartbeat Action not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66123544/debezium-heartbeat-action-not-firing) but it did not resolve my issue.

Here is my source connector config for postgres. It is generating heatbeat events after every 5 seconds. I have confirmed that by checking kafka topic but the issue is that it is not updating the row in the database heartbeat table. Any suggestions?

```
{
    "name": "postgres-localdb-source-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "postgres",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "slot.name":"debezium",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "postgres",
        "database.dbname" : "postgres",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver2",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.dbserver2",
        "schema.include": "inventory",
        "tables.include": "customers,heartbeat",
        "publication.autocreate.mode" : "filtered",
        "max.batch.size":"20480",
        "max.queue.size":"81920",
        "poll.interval.ms":"100",
        "heartbeat.interval.ms": "5000",
        "heartbeat.action.query" :"INSERT INTO heartbeat (id, ts) VALUES (1, NOW()) ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET ts=EXCLUDED.ts;"
    } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to share your `heartbeat` table with a DDL. Your `heartbeat` table have a primary key? Debezium only track updates and deletes if table have PK defined. Also try to share your debezium version because this propertiers change from version to version.

Try a UPDATE without WHERE to test if the problem is in your query. Check if your heartbeat in your schema public or inventory and add as a prefix in your query.

```
UPDATE inventory.heartbeat SET ts = NOW();
```

On your `tables.include` add for each table a prefix with schema.

```
"tables.include": "inventory.customers,inventory.heartbeat",
```

On `tables.include` try to change to `tables.include.list`. Source: [https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.6/connectors/mysql.html#:~:text=connector%20configuration%20property.-,table.include.list,-empty%20string](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.6/connectors/mysql.html#:%7E:text=connector%20configuration%20property.-,table.include.list,-empty%20string)

```
"tables.include.list": "inventory.customers,inventory.heartbeat",
```